# In Cordova, how can I specify different package names for ios and android?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

Due to legacy factors, the package names of my Android and iOS apps are different. Currently Cordova seems to be injecting the widget id attribute from config.xml into both when building. Is there no way to customize this? If I edit the AndroidManifest.xml directly, I expect it will get overwritten pretty soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is now built into CLI (finally):

In you your config.xml file-

Example:

```
<widget
    android-packageName="com.example.android"
    ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.example.ios">
```

Source:

<strike>https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/src/configparser/ConfigParser.js#L92</strike>

Edit: (Cordova-Lib has since been moved)

https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-common/src/ConfigParser/ConfigParser.js#L109

Comment: Is there any equivalent for the `windows` platform?

Answer (score 1):

A way to automate this is by adding in an after prepare hook.  I started out with the example of how to Replace Text Depending on Environment from here: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/.

I've got a project.json in my project that specifies what id I want to use for each platform:

```
{ 
    "android": 
    {
        "app_id": "<my Android Package name>"
    },
    "ios": 
    {
        "app_id": "<my iOS Bundle Identifier>"
    }
}
```

Then in the /hooks directory I have an /after_prepare directory with a replace_text.js as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// this plugin replaces arbitrary text in arbitrary files
//

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var rootdir = process.argv[2];

function replace_string_in_file(filename, to_replace, replace_with) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8");

    var result = data.replace(to_replace, replace_with);
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, result, "utf8");
}

function update_app_id(rootdir, platform, configobj) {
    var appId = configobj[platform].app_id,
        stringToReplace = "<value of the widget id property in the config.xml>";

    if (platform === "android") {

        replace_string_in_file(path.join(rootdir, "platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml"), stringToReplace, appId);
        replace_string_in_file(path.join(rootdir, "platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml"), stringToReplace, appId);

    } else if (platform === "ios") {

        replace_string_in_file(path.join(rootdir, "platforms/ios/<app name>/<app name>-Info.plist"), stringToReplace, appId);
        replace_string_in_file(path.join(rootdir, "platforms/ios/<app name>/config.xml"), stringToReplace, appId);

    }
}

if (rootdir) {
    var ourconfigfile = path.join(rootdir, "project.json");
    var configobj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ourconfigfile, "utf8"));

    // Update each platform's specific configuration/properties files
    update_app_id(rootdir, "android", configobj);
    update_app_id(rootdir, "ios", configobj);
}
```

Please make sure to replace the values indicated with < > brackets with the values that pertain to your app/project.

Comment: Good news, it looks like they have added this ability to Cordova-lib and hopefully it'll be available in the next version: https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/105

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** *This has not been tested, but i think it should work.*

After creating a new IOS platform in Cordova CLI, Edit the package name in the files below.

`app/platforms/ios/<APP_NAME>/config.xml`
`app/platforms/ios/www/config.xml`

To avoid an ugly complication, i suggest you try this first in a different Git Branch of your project.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid editing the `platforms` directories as I don't check them into the repo.